# Accesing the id from a route in node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

I have written the following node.js code:

```
router.get("/author-edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  res.render("author-edit");
});

router.post("/author-edit/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  let article_ID = req.params.id;
  let update_data = [req.body.article_title, req.body.article_subtitle, req.body.article_body, article_ID];
  let sqlQuery = `UPDATE articles SET article_title = ?, article_subtitle = ?, article_body = ? WHERE article_id = ?`;
  global.db.run(sqlQuery, update_data, 
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        res.redirect("/author/author-homepage")
      }
    }
  )
});
```

this way the post method does redirect me back to the homepage, and returns no errors, but the data in the table isn't updated.

While I know this is probably not the right way to do this, is there a way I can use/access the 'id' bit from the route "/author-edit/:id" itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but probably you have to `await` the result.
Something like this: `router.post("/author-edit/:id", async(req, res, next) => { [...]`

And `await global.db.run [...]`

Comment: tried, to no avail, thankyou for the suggestion though